# Google Analytics Event Tracking with utm.gif event parameters

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to track an event on server side using google analytcis. previously i had it working on my front end using this in an onclick event

```
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "listings-stuff", "getNumber", "84268"])
```

it worked fine, but when i try getting it to work on my back end like below. it doesnt track.

```
   http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmac=UA-XXXXXXX-1&utmcc=__utma%3D34850447.1171799361.1426999660.1426999660.1426999660.2%3B%2B__utmb%3D34850447%3B%2B__utmc%3D34850447%3B%2B__utmz%3D34850447.1426222660.2.2.utmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%3B%2B__utmv%3D34850447.-%3B&utmdt=-&utmfl=-&utmje=0&utmn=7492790953&utmp=%2Fwm%2Ffrontend%2Fwww%2Findex.php&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdev%2Ffrontend%2Fwww%2Fsale%2Fstuff%2Fview%2F%3Fid%3D85931&utmsc=-&utmsr=-&utmt=event&utme=5%28_trackEvent%2Alistings-stuff%2AgetNumber%29%284268%29&utmul=-&utmwv=5.2.5&utmhn=abc.com
```

any idea what i'm missing? or doing wrong? thanks

Comment: This is old tracking code. Since afaik the processing engine for analytics has switched to Universal Analytics yiu should use the measurement protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) instead of fiddling around with gif images, MP being especially developed to allow tracking without the js code.